# Iterating over array in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB where a document called Auditlog resides.
The simplified structure is as follows:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "A",
        "messages": [
            {
                "gps": {
                    "src": "GPS"
                },
                "ts": "0"
            }
        ]
    },
        {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "B",
        "messages": [
            {
                "gps": {
                    "src": "DR"
                },
                "ts": "1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to filter the document to get all entries that have src: GPS. 
The result also needs to show the ID.
I have no idea on how to accomplish this.
I tried using the 'IN'-operator but without luck.
Using the 'IN'-operator makes it impossible to display the ID.
I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM c
IN Auditlog.messages
WHERE c.gps.src = "GPS"
```

The result is correct but I need the ID to be displayed in the result.
The following just results in an array of empty objects:

```
SELECT c.id FROM c
IN Auditlog.messages
WHERE c.gps.src = "GPS"
```

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.id AS id
FROM c JOIN a IN c.messages
WHERE a.gps.src = "GPS"
```

result will be

```
[
    {
        "id": "1"
    },
    {
        "id": "2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!